# Is Lynda's react.js video too out of date to use (based off this error)?

Tags: reactjs

You shouldn't need to view the video to answer my question, but it is available here: http://www.lynda.com/React-js-tutorials/React-js-syntax/379264/413770-4.html

I'm starting to learn react.js for the very first time (I'm pretty skilled in HTML/Javascript already), but the very first simple project is not working correctly.

The example code they give, should output "Hello World" to the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://--.--/react-0.13.3.min.js"></script>
        <title>My First React File</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        React.render(React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello World'), document.body);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Facebook's github has a much more up-to-date react file, 15.0.1, so my code only differs with the updated files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://--.--/react-15.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://--.--/react-dom-15.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>My First React File</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <script>
        React.render(React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello World'), document.body);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Their example outputs "Hello World" correctly, and mine does nothing.

Should I be using a different training to learn React? I feel silly asking a question about such a simple line of code.

PS: I had to censor the file names to meet Stack Overflow standards of not using URL shorteners, but they are the files located here: https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html

Edit: I just noticed the video just came out on 2/17/16, so it can't be that out of date.. must be my mistake somewhere? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since react v0.14 `React.render` is not available any more, instead you should use `ReactDOM.render()`

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it. Looks like I will not be using this video for training then.

Comment: @kaisle migration guide from v.0.13 is quite simple (well, it's very simple) so if you like that video you can continue. Most stuff isn't changed so you should not get errors frequently.