# Lynda.com React.js Objects are not valid as a React Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just started learning React.js and have been using a Lynda.com to get the hang of things. Even though the video series is outdated as mentioned in [an earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873004/is-lyndas-react-js-video-too-out-of-date-to-use-based-off-this-error), I've been able to piece together the project with the help of other Stack posts and Google. But this error has me stumped.

I'm at the point of trying to add new notes to a bulletin board app. When I click on the add button (on the top right of the screen) it throws a React Minified #31 error, saying the object I'm using is not valid as a React child. I'm thinking it has to do with the button I just created, but I have no idea how to fix this.

I'm using React version 15.3.1 and Babel version 5.8.29 (as used in the tutorial).

Note.js

```
 var Note = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {editing: false}
    },
    edit: function() {
        this.setState({editing: true});
    },
    save: function() {
        // var val = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.newText).value;
        this.props.onChange(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.newText).value, 
            this.props.index);
        this.setState({editing: false});
    },
    remove: function() {
        this.props.onRemove(this.props.index);
    },
    renderDisplay: function() {
        return (
            <div className="note">
                <p>{this.props.children}</p>
                <span>
                    <button onClick={this.edit}
                            className="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>
                    <button onClick={this.remove}
                            className="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"/>
                </span>
            </div>
            );
    },
    renderForm: function() {
        return (
            <div className="note">
            <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children} 
            className="form-control"></textarea>
            <button onClick={this.save} className="btn btn-success btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" />
            </div>
            )
    },
    render: function() {
        if (this.state.editing) {
            return this.renderForm();
        }
        else {
            return this.renderDisplay();
        }
    }
});

var Board = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        count: function(props, propName) {
            if (typeof props[propName] !== "number") {
                return new Error ('The count property must be a number');
            }
            if (props[propName] > 100) {
                return new Error ('Creating' + props[propName] + 'is silly');
            }
        }
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
       return {
            notes: []
       }; 
    },
    add: function(text){
        var array = this.state.notes;
        array.push(text);
        this.setState({notes:array});
    },
    update: function(newText, i) {
        var array = this.state.notes;
        array[i] = newText;
        this.setState({notes:array});


    },
    remove: function(i) {
        var array = this.state.notes;
        array.splice(i, 1);
        this.setState({note:array});

    },
    eachNote: function(note, i) {
        return (
            <Note key={i}
                index={i}
                onChange={this.update}
                onRemove={this.remove}
            >{note}</Note>
        );
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div className="board">
            {this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}
            <button className="btn btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-plus" 
                    onClick={this.add}></button>
        </div>
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(<Board count={10}/>, 
    document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually in your `Board` class.  You're passing `this.add` as an event handler to the button's `onClick` property.  Keep in mind that [event handlers are always passed an event as the first parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handler's_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value), which means that in your `this.add` function, you're adding an `Event` object to your `notes` state, not a string, like the current signature implies.  Then, when the `eachNote` function is executing, it's trying to render that `Event` as a child of your `Note` component, which is what is causing this error.

If you're trying to add a new note, chances are you won't want it to have any text in it at all.  So I think you could safely ignore the event that is being passed to `this.add`.

```
add: function() {
    var array = this.state.notes;
    array.push('');
    this.setState({notes:array});
},
```

Comment: So should my add function look like this instead?
`add: function(text){
   var array = this.state.notes;
   array.push(text);
  this.setState({notes})
}'
`
Or am I completely off?

Comment: No, that's just going to change the way that you're adding the event to the array.  The result will be the same.  Let me ask this: What do you expect `text` to be inside of the `add` function?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. The way it's explain in the video, and the way I'm understanding things, I want text to be added to the notes array when I hit the add button. This will create a new note and place in on the board.

Comment: Well yeah, the variable `text` is being added to the `notes` array, but what I'm trying to say is that `text` doesn't contain the information that you think it does.  `text` is the event that was fired when you clicked the button.  Add a `console.log(text)` inside `this.add` and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Ah I see! So text isn't defined. And I can't use newText sine that's to update any text that's already found on a note. So I need to set text before it's sent to the click handler, but where do I set it? Or am I still really far off?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you expect `text` to contain.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Sure. Wish I could move this into a chat but I lack the needed reputation at the moment. So when I click the add button, I create a new note. The note has an edit and a delete button. When I click edit, it will open the text area to add any new text. The new text is what I would expect `text` to be at this point. This should be added to the notes array that is created at the `getInitialState` function.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121951/lynda-com-react-js-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child

Comment: It won't let me talk in the chat room since I have less than 20 reputation. Lame! But yeah, my above comment is what I expect to happen with the app at this point.

Comment: You should be able to now :)

Comment: It's still not letting me for some reason. Let's just keep going here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121952/discussion-between-michael-parker-and-dani-moss).

Comment: Try using this ^ instead

Comment: It took moving things to a chat, but Michael Parker and I figured it out. Thanks for the help Michael. Figures it would be something simple that broke the entire app. lolz